# How to Iterate through the std::list<int> in this code

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdlist

I want to iterate through the list1 after the list2 inside that block.
please tell how to make that happen. i have a guess why thats not working but have no idea to make it happen

```
enum type {VALID,INVALID};
#define ADD_A(x,y) addtolist x(#x,VALID,y);
#define ADD_B(x,y) addtolist x(#x,INVALID,y);
class addtolist {
  public:
    std::string name;
    int val;
    std::list<int> list1;
    std::list<int> list2;
    std::list<int>::iterator v;
    std::list<int>::iterator w;
    addtolist(std::string name, type _val, int range);
};

class newlist {
  public:
    newlist(){
    ADD_A(ob1,5);
    ADD_B(ob2,5);
    }
};

addtolist::addtolist( std::string name, type _val,  int range ) {
    name = name;
    val = _val;
    int i;
    if (val==0){
        for(i=0;i<=range;i++){
            list1.push_back(i);
        }
        for (v = list1.begin(); v != list1.end(); ++v){
            std::cout <<"\nvalid list == "<<*v << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"\n size of list1 == "<< list1.size()<<std::endl;
    }else if (val==1){
       for(i=0;i<=range;i++){
           list2.push_back(i);
       }
   for ( w = list2.begin(); w != list2.end(); ++w){
           std::cout <<"\nINVALID LIST == "<<*w<< std::endl;
       }
// i dont know why this gets zero and also the loop does not work and how to make this work
       std::cout<<"\n THIS BECOMES ZERO == "<< list1.size()<<std::endl;
       for (v = list1.begin(); v != list1.end(); ++v){
           std::cout <<"\nVALID LIST == "<<*v << std::endl;
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
    newlist a;
}
```

problem is in the part  *else if*  block ie. iterating the list1 and the *list1.size();* ..

Comment: -1 *"if there are any errors in the code please ignore, problem is in the part else if block ie. iterating the list1 and the list1.size();*" Just post a code snippet related to the problem, not the hole codebase. Also format properly your code, not just copy-paste it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just an intention to review (or debug) the code which was just copy-pasted into SO.

Comment: This is a situation, where i cant understand the problem in the code or the mistake i made. Sorry i cant choose exact topic or explain the problem correctly. Only way i can explain my problem is copy pasting the code.

Comment: What scares me is that people might actually write code without indentation.

Comment: This code won't even compile ... Did you even try ?

Comment: Yes, i have, compiled and i can see the output of the statements except for the part i have problem with. Here in the above code i have missed semicolons and now i have edited that also.

Comment: Please do not get in the habit of zero indentation.  Hopefully the sample below will be useful in this regard as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design reason for having two internal `std::list` containers is not clear.  Only one of the `list` containers is filled, dependent on the `enum type _val` value passed to the

```
addtolist(std::string name, type _val, int b);
```

constructor.  In order to have a non-empty `list1` container for an `INVALID` type, the body of the constructor will have to change accordingly.  In other words, the second object `ob2` has elements for `list2`, because container number two is the only `list` that has been populated.

If in doubt, check the `list1.empty()` condition for both `enum type` values, which is not really necessary since the `list1.size()` value is already shown as zero for the `INVALID` type.  Ultimately the `for` loop which traverses `list1` for the `INVALID` type is behaving exactly as it supposed to for an empty container.

One way to always have `list1` filled, is to move the `list1 for loop` above the if statement logic that checks for the `enum type`.  This is only an example.  The actual design modification is up to the OP.

```
addtolist::addtolist( std::string name, type _val,  int range ) 
{
   name = name;
   val = _val;
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<=range;i++)
   {
      list1.push_back(i);
   }

   if (val==VALID)
   {
      // 
      // for loop that prints list1 content and other code follows as before
      //
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Reason for having 2 lists is before pushing the elements of INVALID into the list2, i want to compare them with the elements of VALID (list1). Before that i tried printing the contents of list1 which will be empty for ob2. Is comparing possible by the way i am trying.Please suggest me some way to do that. Thank You

Comment: @vrsm You want to compare the internal lists (e.g. `list1` and `list2`) of two different instances of the `addtolist` class.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No i don't want to compare two lists after they are filled, i only want to compare each element of **INVALID** with the elements of **list1(VALID)** which was filled, before pushing the elements of **INVALID** into **list2** .

Comment: @vrsm Before assuming that there are two completely configured instances and ignoring that it is bad practice to have all class data members public access, you are specifically saying `instance1.list1 == potentialList of instance TWO`, correct?

Comment: @vrsm If this is your goal, then create a separate `list` container prior to creating a second `addtolist` instance.  There will have to be a new constructor that takes this new potential list and the correct value for the `enum type` based on the result of comparing the first instance's `list1` contents to a list container that is about to be used for a second instance.  If you understand the comparison operations available through the `std::list` container, then this is straightforward.  Please modify the posted question accordingly.